# Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused. YOLO on Google Colab

Tags: server, connection, google-colaboratory, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to test out YOLO on google colab for the first time and keep running into this odd error:

[image: 1]

This is the line of code that I run:

```
!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg /mydrive/yolov3/backup/yolov3_custom_last.weights /mydrive/images/I5.png -thresh 0.3
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to that? I'm having problems trying to open any graphical program using the terminal

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same, but resolved by updating "**config file**".
There might be some unbalanced "**[**" or "**#**" characters.

Solution 1: Update your config file as in this format  https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg

Solution 2: For some, using `-dont_show` flag in detection command has worked.

eg: `!./darknet detector test data/obj.data   cfg/yolov3_V1_config.cfg   /mydrive/yolov3_V1_config_last.weights /mydrive/yolov3/Poachers/pic2.jpg -thresh 0.3 -dont_show`

Answer (score 2):

-dont_show was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

In `yolov3_custom.cfg` file, uncomment the two lines under # Testing

```
# Testing
batch=1
subdivisions=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the error is because I am getting the same. If you write the following after the line of code you will be able to see the image:

```py
imshow('predictions.jpg')
```